# Pointer error in Directed Graph in Python

Tags: python, directed-graph, graph-traversal

I'm trying to implement a Directed graph in python by creating a class `Vertex`. A vertex has the `name` and the `adjacent` as a list containing another `instance of class Vertex` . below is the code.

The problem is that when I assign `node b` as the `adjacent` node from `node a`. the pointer of `node b` is assigned to both adjacent of `a` and `b` which is not my intention.

I also have the picture debug mode below the code showing that the pointer of node b is also assigned to itself.

how to fix it?

```
class Vertex:

    def __init__(self, name, adjacent=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.adjacent = adjacent

    def add_adjacent(self, vertex):
        
        self.adjacent.append(vertex)
        
        
class Graph:
    # directed graph
    def __init__(self, edge_list):
        vertices = {}
        for o, d in edge_list:
            
            # print(o, d)
            if o not in vertices:
                v = Vertex(o)
                vertices[o] = v
            else:
                v = vertices[o]
                
            if d not in vertices:
                u = Vertex(d)
                vertices[d] = u
            else:
                u = vertices[d]
            

            if u not in v.adjacent:
                print(v.name, ' adds ', u.name)
                v.add_adjacent(u)
            
        self.vertices = vertices
    
    def get_vertex_names(self):
        return list(self.vertices.keys())
    
    def get_adjacent(self, vertex):
        return self.vertices[vertex].adjacent
    


# test Vertex
edges = [
           ['a', 'b'],
           ['a', 'c'],
           ['a', 'd'],
           ['b', 'c'],
           ['c', 'b'],
         ]

g = Graph(edges)
# g.vertices
```

[error can be seen in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0gdy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote this:

```
    def __init__(self, name, adjacent=[]):
```

There is a subtle "gotcha",
summarized by a simple rule,

**Avoid using mutable container as a default arg.**

You want this:

```
    def __init__(self, name, adjacent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.adjacent = adjacent or []
```

In the original, there is a single `list`
for all vertices (since caller always lets it default).
That list was created at `def` time.
In contrast, the `or []` clause
constructs a *new* list at execution time
each time through, rather than once during definition.

https://dollardhingra.com/blog/python-mutable-default-arguments/

https://towardsdatascience.com/python-pitfall-mutable-default-arguments-9385e8265422